# How to move geographical data from MS Access to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, spatial

For 20 years I've been working with MS Access, with much VBA involved.
I have a lot of geographical data in Access and I'm preparing to move to SQL Server because it supports geographical data types, and because it has a good connection with QGIS, in which I want to show and query my geographical data efficiently in a map.

Basically, my geographical data in Access comprise my GPS tracks that I've collected in 20 years, altogether about 5000 tracks with an average 800 points per track. In Access I have two tables for them:

1. `[tbl Track]` with metadata describing the track (e.g. distance, start date and time, duration, maximum elevation etc.).
2. `[tbl TrackGeo]` with the tracks themselves in geographical terms. Attributes:

   ID (autonum, PK)

   TrackID (long, FK to [tbl Track])

   LatWGS84 (double)

   LonWGS84 (double)

Moving `[tbl Track]` to SQL Server is easy, but it gets difficult for me (newbie in SQL Server and its geographical data types!) to move the geograhical data to SQL Server in a spatial data field.

My idea is:
Put the data of `[tbl TrackGeo]` per track in a geography spatial data field (type linestring) in `[tbl Track]` in SQL Server.

My question is:
What is the best approach to accomplish this, preferably (if possible) using VBA from within MS Access?

Comment: I believe the [SQL Server Import and Export Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/import-and-export-data-with-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-ver15) shall be enough for you to accomplish this task properly. Have you seen it?

Comment: Yes, I know it. But can such a move be done programmatically with for instance VBA?

Comment: Start with a straight lift-and-shift to SQL Server, perhaps using SSMA for Access. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54255  Then you can start using the SQL Server geography types and functions.  Note if you're still using Access as a Front-End you'll need to use Views or Passthrough queries.

Answer (score 0):

I would use VBA to construct & export your spatial data into the Well Known Text (WKT) format. SQL Server supports importing data from this format & as it is text based it is fairly easy syntactically.

Comment: Thanks. Some of my tracks have more than 10000 points. Does SQL Server support that if I put such a track in one geography attribute, type linestring?

Comment: can't find any published limits but that is not a lot of nodes so don´t think there will be a problem